# Telnet to a WebService - HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request

Tags: java, web-services

I have an error using `HTTPService`. I have written a sample code and it looks like this:

```
import java.net.InetSocketAddress;

import com.kivar.lumina.services.handlers.LuminaSearchService;
import com.sun.net.httpserver.HttpServer;

public class LuminaWebService {

    public static void main( String[] args ) throws Exception {
        HttpServer server = HttpServer.create( new InetSocketAddress( 8000 ), 0 );
        server.createContext( "/luminaSearchService ", new LuminaSearchService() );
        server.start();
    }

}
```

And my handler class

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.OutputStream;

import com.kivar.lumina.services.interfaces.SearchService;
import com.sun.net.httpserver.HttpExchange;
import com.sun.net.httpserver.HttpHandler;

public class LuminaSearchService extends Thread implements SearchService, HttpHandler {

    @Override
    public void handle( HttpExchange arg0 ) throws IOException {
        setDaemon( true );
        String response = "This is the response";
        arg0.sendResponseHeaders( 200, response.length() );
        OutputStream os = arg0.getResponseBody();
        os.write( response.getBytes() );
        os.close();
    }

}
```

When I try to do telnet using the cmd prompt and this syntax,

> telnet 127.0.0.1 8000

I am getting an error saying that

```
HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
Connection to the host lost.
```

Please let me know the mistake I am committing here. Thanks a ton.

Comment: Do you send any HTTP headers at all in your telnet? Or does it fail immediately without even waiting for input? If the second, it is a bug...

Comment: Actually I don't know whats the correct way to test this simple web service. When I do `telnet 127.0.0.1 8000` I get a blank screen, but when I try to type `GET /luminaSearchService`(which is not even visible on the cmd prompt) I get that error

Comment: You need to specify the HTTP version, i.e. `GET /luminaSearchService HTTP/1.0`. Then hit return twice, i.e. leave an empty line to indicate end of request.

Comment: @LPD well, there you are then: your request is indeed incorrect, therefore the 400 error is expected. Try and google for "telnet HTTP".

Comment: @LPD alternatively, use a command-line HTTP client, such as `wget` or `curl`.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Rup and @fge. I got it working, but I did not understand why am not able to see the command that I key in thats, `GET /luminaSearchService HTTP/1.0` and also why do hit return twice..

Comment: Cannot see command: that's up to your telnet client not echoing back. You could download e.g. PuTTY to use instead if you want. Hit return twice: that's the HTTP protocol; you send a blank line to indicate the end of request.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your web server doesn't seem to support HTTP 1.0 anymore. For HTTP 1.1, you have to specify the version number and the host name:

```
GET /luminaSearchService HTTP/1.1
Host: 127.0.0.1
```

With the Windows command window, it's *normal* that you don't see what you're typing.

Wouldn't it be easier if you pointed your web browser at this URL since it's a simple GET request?

Comment: Yeah. I had done that already, but wanted to test this telnet and understand the same. Thanks a lot

Comment: I have a small doubt, can we send multiple GET requests once I connect using telnet?

Comment: HTTP 1.1 should wait for another request after the response for the previous request has been sent. But it usually has a very short timeout (typically 5 seconds in newer implementations) and will close the connection quickly. For HTTP 1.0, you can achieve it by specifying "Connection: keep-alive". But it most cases it closes the connection anyway since HTTP 1.0 misses chunked transfer encoding.

Answer (score 1):

Your webservice may be expecting some request or header params and hence throwing this error. Can you provide the contract of the webservice as well.

Comment: Am sorry, but what exactly you mean by the contract here? I have added my handler class as well in my question now, so please have a look. Thanks a lot for ur time

Comment: By contract I mean, the specification of your webservice. What is the URL, what are the request/header params required/optional, etc. Once we know what webservice is expecting to process the request correctly then only we can understand why it is throwing 400 BAD request.